# ASP MVC prevent submit form with jquery function on separate js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to submit a form via ajax using the following code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form-discount', function (e) {

  e.preventDefault()

  $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
    });
});
```

But this is reaching the controller before reaching this javascript code, so it hits twice the controller action. How can I avoid this behaviour? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false from your call back to stop the page from performing a full postback.

Something like this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form-discount', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
    });
    return false;//stop postback
});
```

Comment: This is not working. The problem is that the submit reaches the controller action before the $(document).on submit function. Any idea?